# FLUTTER I have problem 'openssl/ssl/h' file not found when add cloud_firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, openssl, cocoapods

Lexical or preprocessor issue (xcode): 'openssl/ssl/h' file not found
/Users/zenx/FlutterProject/setup_firebase/ios/Pods/gRPC-Core/src/core/tsi/ssl/key_logging/ssl_key_logging.h:22:9

I use CLI or setup manual, still have this problem. help meee

i can add firebase_core, firebase_auth, firebase_storage but when add cloud_firestore encounter error.

Comment: Looks like Xcode can't compile ssl_key_logging (see https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/src/core/tsi/ssl/key_logging/ssl_key_logging.h i.e. line 23) because it cannot `#include <openssl/ssl.h>`

Answer (score 2):

It's worked for me:

1. In the console, navigate to the iOS folder:

`$ cd ios`

2. Delete the file:

`$ rm -rf Pods Podfile.lock`

3. Next, enter the command:

`$ pod cache clean --allpod`

4. And finally:

`$ pod install`

[Source](https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/3203#issuecomment-743789416)